# Square root complex function

Tags: complex-analysis

$f(x+iy)=\sqrt{|x||y|} $ for all $x,y \,\,\epsilon \,\, \mathbb R$.

Show that $f$ satisfies Cauchy-Riemann equations at $0$ but is not analytic at $0$.

Attempt at a solution:

Since the function has only a real part, $Re\,f= u(x,y)=\sqrt{|x||y|}$ and $Im\,f=v(x,y)=0.$ Need to show that all partial derivatives are $0$ and discontinuous at $0$. But taking the partial derivatives gives $\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}=\frac{1}{2}\frac{\sqrt{|y|}}{\sqrt{|x|}}$ which does not exist at $0$.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}(0,0)=\lim_{t\to0}\frac{u(0+t,0)-u(0,0)}{t}=\lim_{t\to0}0=0$

$\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}(0,0)=\lim_{t\to0}\frac{u(0,0+t)-u(0,0)}{t}=\lim_{t\to0}0=0$

If $x>0$ and $y>0$ then:

$\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}(x,y)=\frac{y}{2\sqrt{xy}}=\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\frac{y}{x}}$. If we let $y=\alpha x$ in this region then:

$\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}(x,\alpha x)=\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\frac{\alpha x}{x}}=\frac{\sqrt{\alpha}}{2}$.

This means that if we approach $(0,0)$ through the line $y=\alpha x$ then the partial derivatives in $x$ at these points approaches $\frac{\sqrt{\alpha}}{2}$. Hence the partial derivatives in $x$ are not continuous at $0$. A similar thing happens for the partials in $y$.

Answer (score 1):

Note that if $x \in \mathbb{R}\setminus \{ 0 \}$, you have $\frac{f(0+x)-f(0)}{x} =\frac{0-0}{x} = 0$, and similarly $\frac{f(0+ix)-f(0)}{ix} =\frac{0-0}{ix} = 0$.